# Visual Studio Installer doesn't show installed instance of Visual Sudio

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio Installer shows empty page on the Installed tab

[image: Empty Installed tab]

but the visual studio is installed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be in missing **VSDownloadCache** folder. It stores information about installed instances in the _Instances subfolder.

You can change this folder location on the installation location tab of the installer (if it hasn't exist yet):
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I removed VS folder from Program Files and reinstall VS, this solved the problem.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eRuY.png